# Load viewControllers to scroller,and let them know they are presented

Tags: ios, objective-c

We have an app that should show some main `scrollview`.
In this scroller, there should be a few pages, where each one of them is a `view controller class` by its own . (is it good for performance? )

So ,what we will do is to load them to the scroller at the start.
Problem: when we scroll , i want each and every page to know that the scroller is now moving, thats because when we scroll to view controller 3 , i want to animate him while scrolling to him/when we end deceleration.

How could we make one big scroller, that loads view controllers to it, and let them know always what happens ? (delegates? )

Comment: u tried Page controller?

Comment: Seems a bit weird to put view controllers in scrollview. You can probably do the same with a collectionview (which would tell you which cell was pressed)

Comment: UIPageViewController gives everything you need. Collectionview is also a good option.

Comment: have u tried container view?

Comment: but there is a scroller/collection in one container, he knows what happens, but he must transmit that to all other controllers, so, should he do that with delegates ?